# In iOS, how does autorotation work behind the scene?

Tags: ios

In iOS, how does autorotation work behind the scene?

1) When and how often is shouldAutorotate called by iOS?

2) At what point (relative to the view controller callbacks) does window set the frame of your root view controller based on what you return in supportedInterfaceOrientations?

3) At what point does iOS perform the autorotation animation relative to the other callbacks.  For example, is it before viewWillAppear for all child view controllers of that root view controller?

Comment: have you made any effort to find the answer to those question? like e.g. _browsing Apple docs_, _making sample codes_, etc... most of the questions (I mean, all) could have been answered if you had done a little this or a little that...

Comment: Yes I have read UIViewController class reference and another doc on this.  It doesn't explain my question above.

Comment: for me it took 10 minutes to use google and to read the docs and find reasonable answers...

Comment: I would like exact answers on when shouldAutorotate is fired and when the frame is set.  I don't believe that's in the doc or answers you listed.

Comment: I'm sure whether you _do not believe_ or you _do not want to believe_. if something is not clear to you or you just don't see the relationship between things, please let me know your doubt – I'm happy to help you. but please bear in mind, you will _never_ find such exact answer in the Apple's docs like e.g. _"Dear Boon! If we may, let us inform the iOS will invoke your such and such classes' `shouldAutorotate` method if (...). Sincerely, Apple"_

Answer (score 2):

The reason that none of those things is in the documentation is that none of them is subject to any contractual guarantees. Just implement the methods to do what the names say. If you're going to make assumptions based on your own empirical observations or those posted here by others then expect your code to fail as and when iOS is updated.

Comment: this answer actually sounds like you had a decent amount of suffering because of this :-)

Comment: Back when I was fresh faced and naive, errors were made around the sequencing of `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` versus other calls (especially when a view controller is being prepared for initial display); I take some comfort from the fact that they were accidental and simply not uncovered until a later version of iOS but nevertheless they were my own stupid fault for imputing contractual guarantees that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

based on the [Apple's official docs about how orientation support works in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html), the answers to your questions may be those extractions from the referred docs:

## 1)

> When the orientation of an iOS–based device changes, the system sends out a `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification to let any interested parties know that the change occurred.

## 2)

> When the user interface rotates, the window is resized to match the new orientation. The window adjusts the frame of its root view controller to match the new size, and this size in turn is propagated down the view hierarchy to other views.

## 3)

> 1. The window calls the root view controller’s `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.
>      Container view controllers forward this message on to the currently displayed content view controllers.
> 2. The window adjusts the bounds of the view controller’s view. This causes the view to layout its subviews, triggering the view controller’s `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. When this method runs, you can query the app object’s `statusBarOrientation` property to determine the current user interface layout.
> 3. The view controller’s `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method is called. This method is called from within an animation block so that any property changes you make are animated at the same time as other animations that comprise the rotation.
> 4. The animation is executed.
> 5. The window calls the view controller’s `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method.
>      Container view controllers forward this message to the currently displayed content view controllers. This action marks the end of the rotation process.

---

*NOTE: you could also make some sample codes to make the experience complete.*